# Missing column from access database in datagridview

Tags: c#, sql, database, ms-access

I have an access database in a windows forms application which I use to populate datagridviews. However one of the columns never displays and when specified within the select statement it returns a "No value given for one or more required parameters"

Here is the current code

```
            string select_Schedules = "SELECT * FROM Schedules";
            conn = new OleDbConnection(constr);
            conn.Open();
            ds = new DataSet();
            adap = new OleDbDataAdapter();
            cmd = new OleDbCommand(select_Schedules, conn);

            adap.SelectCommand = cmd;
            adap.Fill(ds);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;
            dataGridView2.DataSource = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;
            dataGridView3.DataSource = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;
            dataGridView4.DataSource = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;
            conn.Close();
```

The column is indeed contained within the table

[image]

This what the "SELECT * " query returns
[image]
as seen the Show_Date column is missing. When specified through

`SELECT Show_Date FROM Schedules`

it returns the error as previously mentioned.

Comment: Try : SELECT * FROM Schedules

Comment: Apologies, I forgot to paste that within my initial code, it returns the tables as shown

Comment: I bet that you are not looking at the same database that you are querying. Check your connectionstring. Did you use DataDirectory shortcut?

Comment: Thank you! This was indeed the fault, the connection string pointed to an old version of the DB.

Answer (score 0):

As Steve pointed out I had an old connection string in this specific form. A simple mistake indeed.

> I bet that you are not looking at the same database that you are querying. Check your connectionstring. Did you use DataDirectory shortcut? – Steve

So my problem has been solved. Thank you.